# How to configure domain trust and DNS to share content with an external domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, internal-dns

I have two domains (same LAN subnet) lab1.tld & lab2.tld I configured a one-way external trust (with selective authentication) for those domains plus a secondary DNS zone pointing to the "opposite" domain in each of them.

**1 ) dc1.lab1.tld**

- IP: 10.0.0.1
- Incoming Trust: lab2.tld
- Trust Type: External trust
- Primary DNS zone: lab1.tld
- Secondary zone: lab2.tld
- DNS zone transfert allowed to dc1.lab2.local (10.0.0.2)

**2 ) dc1.lab2.tld**

- IP: 10.0.0.2
- Outgoing Trust: lab1.tld
- Trust Type: External trust
- Primary DNS zone: lab2.tld
- Secondary zone: lab1.tld
- DNS zone transfert allowed to dc1.lab1.local (10.0.0.1)

**3 ) server.lab2.tld**

- IP: 10.0.0.3
- Share: D:\myshare

Currently I can affect permissions on shared directory in lab2.tld domain to users that belong to lab1.tld domain.

I can resolve lab1.tld FQDNs from lab2.tld & lab2.tld FQDNs from lab1.tld

Unfortunetly I can't access my shared folder sitting in lab2.tld domain from lab1.tld domain. Note that no matter if I use an \server.lab2.local\myshare or \10.0.0.3\myshare from lab2.tld domain, non of them work properly.

How to configure domain trust and DNS to share content with an external domain, what I am missing with the current configuration?

Comment: `Unfortunetly I can't access my shared folder sitting in lab2.tld domain from lab1.tld domain. Note that no matter if I use an \server.lab2.local\myshare or \10.0.0.3\myshare from lab2.tld domain, non of them work properly.` - What does that mean exactly? What happens?

Comment: From "server.lab1.tld" I'm trying to browse fileshare on "server.lab2.tld" with explorer using either "\\server.lab2.local\myshare" OR "\\10.0.0.3l\myshare". There is an error message "Windows cannot access \\server.lab2.local\myshare" (...) Error code: 0x80004005 Unspecified error"

Comment: Selective Authentication requires granting the "Allowed To Authenticate" permission on the target computer objects.

Comment: @GregAskew, I granted "Allowed To Authenticate" permission to my test user (lab1.tld\testuser) on: server.lab2.tld and dc1.lab2.tld, plus to dc1.lab1.tld (lab1.tld domain controller) on dc1.lab2.tld. I can't mount access file share on "server.lab2.tld" from trusted domain "lab1.tld". What Am I missing here?

Comment: I can see multiple entries for failed sessions on server.lab2.local security event log: "Event: 4625. Security ID: NULL SID (...) Authentication package: NTLM (...)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using two one-way trusts instead of a two-way trust? That seems unnecessarily complex. Also don't think you need a secondary DNS zone, conditional forwarder is probably simpler. Also see the following, there may be some additional steps: https://www.anexinet.com/blog/what-ms-doesnt-tell-you-how-to-properly-create-a-two-way-external-domain-selective-trust-between-two-seperate-forests/

Comment: I switched to a two ways forest trust (mainly because kerberos doesn't seem to be supported in a one way external trust use case). Note that this time I did not set selective authentication. But again I can't access fileshare, it seem like authentication is failing back to NTLM instead of Kerberos when trying to access fileshare on lab2.tld domain from lab1.tld domain.